# knapsack problem with dp getting my answer wrong

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int [] val = new int[n];
        int [] weight = new int[n];
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            val[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
         for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            weight[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        int cap = sc.nextInt();
        int [][]dp = new int[n+1][cap+1];
        System.out.println(getMaxVal(val, weight, cap, 0, 0, dp));
      
        
    }
    
    public static int getMaxVal(int []val, int []wt, int cap, int index, int valStored, int [][]dp){
        
        if(cap == 0 || index >= val.length){
            return valStored;
        } 
        if(dp[index][cap] != 0) {
            return dp[index][cap];
        }
        
        int n = val.length;
        int withCurrentItem = 0;
        int inittalMaxValue = 0;
        if(cap - wt[index] >=0){
            withCurrentItem = getMaxVal(val, wt, cap - wt[index], index+1, valStored+val[index], dp);
        }
        int withoutCurrentItem = getMaxVal(val, wt, cap, index+1, valStored, dp);
      

        dp[index][cap] = Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem);
        
        return  Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem);
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
}
```

In this 0 / 1 knapsack problem if i use the same code without dp then it works perfectly and all of my test cases pass. but if i do like this way i am getting my some of the test cases failed. What i am doing wrong here please help me out in it.

Comment: I recommend removing the scanner and hardcoding some failing data. What efforts have you made to debug this? It's a good idea to describe your overall logic/approach.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of `Dynamic Programming` is as follows: You have a function that takes some parameters, but its output depends on only particular parameters (if those parameters are the same, the output is always the same) so we don't compute the answer more than once because those parameters are the same and we know the output.

The issue with your dynamic programming is that you assumed that the output of `getMaxVal` depends only on `cap` and `index`, but in fact, it depends on `valStored` as well. But you check `cap` and `index` and assume that the output is the same which is wrong.

One possible solution is that you can extend your memo and include `valStored` as well, but this increases complexity.

Another possible solution (which I recommend) is that you can change the function so that it does not depend on `valStored`.

### How to find such errors in the future

How I approached your problem is as follows: I implemented both `withDP` and `withoutDP` functions, created random inputs and tested these two over and over again, and compared their outputs. When there is some issue, I printed the input and continued further investigation. I'm telling this because you can always follow these steps and try to debug the code yourself.

Here is the code (note that some inputs, `cap` and `index` is the same but output is different)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static ArrayList<String> parameters;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        parameters = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random(0);
        int[] val;
        int[] weight;
        int n;
        int[][] dp;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Test Case: " + counter);
            parameters.clear();
            n = r.nextInt(5) + 5;
            val = new int[n];
            weight = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                val[i] = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                weight[i] = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }

            int cap = r.nextInt(90) + 10;
            dp = new int[n + 1][cap + 1];
            int withDP = getMaxValDP(val, weight, cap, 0, 0, dp);
            int withoutDP = getMaxVal(val, weight, cap, 0, 0);
            if (withDP != withoutDP) {
                System.out.println("With DP: " + withDP);
                System.out.println("Without DP: " + withoutDP);
                System.out.println("input:");
                System.out.println("n = " + n);
                System.out.println("cap = " + cap);

                System.out.print("val:    ");
                for (int i: val) {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("weight: ");
                for (int i: weight) {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
                System.out.println();

                Collections.sort(parameters);
                for (String s: parameters){
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static int getMaxVal(int []val, int []wt, int cap, int index, int valStored){

        if(cap == 0 || index >= val.length){
            parameters.add("cap:  " + cap + ",\tindex: " + index + ",\tvalStored: " + valStored + ",\treturn value: " + valStored);
            return valStored;
        }

        int withCurrentItem = 0;
        if(cap - wt[index] >=0){
            withCurrentItem = getMaxVal(val, wt, cap - wt[index], index+1, valStored+val[index]);
        }
        int withoutCurrentItem = getMaxVal(val, wt, cap, index+1, valStored);

        parameters.add("cap:  " + cap + ",\tindex: " + index + ",\tvalStored: " + valStored + ",\treturn value: " + Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem));
        return Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem);

    }

    public static int getMaxValDP(int []val, int []wt, int cap, int index, int valStored, int [][]dp){

        if(cap == 0 || index >= val.length){
            return valStored;
        }
        if(dp[index][cap] != 0) {
            return dp[index][cap];
        }

        int withCurrentItem = 0;
        if(cap - wt[index] >=0){
            withCurrentItem = getMaxValDP(val, wt, cap - wt[index], index+1, valStored+val[index], dp);
        }
        int withoutCurrentItem = getMaxValDP(val, wt, cap, index+1, valStored, dp);

        dp[index][cap] = Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem);

        return  Math.max(withoutCurrentItem, withCurrentItem);

    }
}
```